# QGIS is crashing when I click on the SVG fill function

Tags: svg

This problem is new from the last two or three days. When I click on the SVG fill in the Layer Styling tool bar

[image]

I get this message in upper left corner

[image]

and after few seconds I get this other message

[image]

and then QGIS crushes. I tried to re-install, but it did not change this problem. The QGIS software used to crush from time to time, but never this often and never often. I am working with the 2.18.9 (64 bit) version that I download from the [QGIS](http://qgis.org/en/site/forusers/download.html#) web site.

Can anyone help me with this topic?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've had this problem before, and it had to do with the default path QGIS uses to search for SVG's did not exist, so QGIS would hang then crash.

Dig into the Settings > Options > System section and try to clear out and reset your default paths:

[image]