# QGIS-bin has stopped working; QGIS crashes at startup

Tags: qgis, svg

How can I recover a functional version of QGIS, and hopefully also recover the project I'm working on? I'm using Windows 7 64 bit. Here is the screenshot.

[image: QGIS crash report dialogue]

I have read the threads to other similar questions and haven't resolved the problem.

1. A new QGIS installation, removing 2.18 La Palmas and replacing with 2.18.11, also did not work
2. Removing C:\Program Files\QGIS 2.18\apps\qgis\processing folder did not work

This crash happened as I was trying to add svg markers to my composer - as a final touch on my completed project! There are just no north arrows (but I did find them in QGIS here: C:\Program Files\QGIS 2.18\apps\qgis\svg\symbol when I tried to add some svg markers I had downloaded. They just don't show up under the svg available markers for arrows in composer? Anyway, something I did in that effort crashed the whole program and all future installations.

Comment: possibly related to this: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/245166/qgis-is-crashing-when-i-click-on-the-svg-fill-function?rq=1

Comment: I tried loading QGIS 2.4 Chugiak and assembling my project one layer at a time. There was an error during loading that didn't crash the program due to Quickmap services plugin. The program crashed with QGIS-bin.exe has stopped working after I added a Quickmap base file?

Comment: It just crashes for any reason after I add any feature.

Comment: This is just a guess, but since it crashed after adding a quickmap layer, try uninstalling the quickmap plugin. If that fixes it, re-install the plugin. If the plugin won't work, try finding base layers from a different souce, such as a WMS.